# CQ5 does not work properly with angular?

Tags: angularjs, aem

I am using angularjs - i should better say i'd love to - for component implementations. But when i try to set up a link, CQ modifies the link and let's it appear broken. The thing is, after the template has been processed, the right data appears in the markup - the link is bascially broken.

```
<li ng-repeat="file in resourceChildren">{{file.name}} (<a href="{{file.path}}">link</a>)</li>
```

becomes

```
<li ng-repeat="file in resourceChildren" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
    layer-it-on.jpg (<img src="/libs/cq/linkchecker/resources/linkcheck_o.gif"
    alt="invalid link: /content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/articles/layer-it-on.jpg" 
    title="invalid link: /content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/articles/layer-it-on.jpg" 
    border="0">link<img src="/libs/cq/linkchecker/resources/linkcheck_c.gif" border="0">) 
</li>
```

Instead of the simple resolution of the templates. The data passed to the controlller, which is used for rendering, is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ng-source directive! (ng-src)

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc

Comment: It was ng-href in the case of a tags.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like an issue with the linkchecker in CQ.  You can disable the linkchecker through the OSGi console.  Here are some instructions:

http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/DisableLinkChecker.html

http://www.wemblog.com/2011/10/how-to-make-sure-that-links-are-always.html

Both of these links refer to 5.4, but apply to 5.5 as well. Hope that helps.